# Is there a way to place blueprinted poles at maximum distances?

Tags: factorio

The current issue I have is with placing Blueprinted Electric Poles over long distances as shown in this GIF:

[image: animated GIF of issue described in the post]

Normally, you are able to hold down LMB, and move. Then once you reach the maximum distance, you'll automatically place another pole. (Provided that there are no other poles nearby too)

However, as seen in the GIF, it doesn't happen for the poles that are blueprinted.

Is there a way to place blueprinted poles at maximum distances?

Note: I do want the roboport to be placed too. I don't want to go through the trouble of running back to just place a roboport.

Comment: Instead of using Big electric pole, why don`t you use Medium electric pole ?

Comment: I am planning to connect the electric and the robo network over a long distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to blueprint two poles, at maximum distance, both with their roboports.

You put down a single pole (your starting point), then place the blueprint over it - you'll get the ghost roboport next to it, and the pole+port ghost at maximum distance, they all get placed by your robots when you approach. Then simply plop down the blueprint again, and you'll get another pole+port ghost at max distance.

Comment: Seems like there is no easy way to do what I want... hopefully they implement it in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that roboport can be placed next to each other, so when you click and drag the roboport + electric pole, it goes to the next minimum placing distance for the combination.  If you want just the electric pole to be placed over long distances, do not add the roboport to it.

Comment: I do want the roboport to be placed too. I don't want to go through the trouble of running back to just place a roboport.